# Am I supposed to do a brew ln after every brew install? (Mac OS Package Manager homebrew)

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, homebrew

I'm not sure I'm using the Mac OS brew package manager properly. Packages don't end up in /usr/local unless I follow a

```
brew install foo
```

with a

```
brew ln foo
```

What makes me suspicious is nearly every quickstart tutorial I see on using brew doesn't indicate that the ln step is required.

Am I missing something?

It's especially annoying when I install something like ffmpeg, that installs a lot of prerequisites. I find myself having to read the log, finding what it installed and manually doing a

```
brew ln yasm
brew ln videolan
brew ln faac
```

etc, for each prerequisite installed. I can't believe it's supposed to work this way. What am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't have to; `brew ln` should be performed automatically after a package is installed.

Answer (score 0):

only if you do a manual compile/install, change formula, non-default location